# Construct iterator from const_iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, const-iterator

I am writing a container class and have created a nested iterator class. Now I am putting in the const_iterator class. Other than a few typedefs, the implementation is near-identical. Do I really have to have the same code twice, or is there a way to have one class use the other's implementation?

Currently I am giving the `iterator` class a private constructor like so:

```
explicit iterator(const_iterator& it): internal{const_cast<pointer>(it.internal)}, begin{const_cast<pointer>(it.begin)}, end{const_cast<pointer>(it.end)}, cycle{it.cycle} {};
```

So in the `const_iterator` class, rather than rewrite the code, I have the following

```
const_iterator& operator+=(difference_type n) {return *this = iterator{*this} += n;}
```

I understand that this is technically not safe, but since users wouldn't be able to convert `const_iterator` to `iterator` is it ok?

A side question: *If I go this route and have `iterator` constructible from `const_iterator`, should it be an operator or constructor?*

Comment: A non-const iterator should not be constructible from a const one - this will break const-correctness. Construction of const iterator from a non-const one is fine.

Comment: You can take a look at the real MS STL implementation [class _Vector_iterator](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/vector#L245).